# Exactly once delivery option for a pubsub subscription is not available for some reason

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am unable to select the 'Exactly once delivery' option for my pubsub push subscription. No where on the internet does it explain why it is greyed out. (See below)

[image]

Tried finding answeres everywhere, looked into docs as well but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like they only allow this feature for the 'pull' option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

More information about Cloud Pub/Sub Exactly Once Delivery and Push Subscriptions: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/exactly-once-delivery#exactly-once_delivery_and_push_subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation :

> Only the pull subscription type supports exactly-once delivery, including subscribers that use the StreamingPull API.